# How to cluster Raster data

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, r, clustering

I have thousands of Raster data concerning the ice coverage at the pole at different times (days) over several years. Now I would like to perform a cluster analysis. I want to split the data into different periods (e.g. 4 seasons) with respect to the ice cover.

Can I perform such a cluster analysis in R? And if, how? (I am a beginner in R, so please keep it as simple as possible. Thanks.)

Or is it possible to use Grass GIS or QGIS (considering the large amount of data)?

Comment: Are you looking at NSIDC sea ice concentration? I think this question needs more concrete details.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! One minor edit I made to your question was to remove your signature etc as per the help which says: 

**Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings**.

Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. 

Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Comment: I am working with daily AMSR-E sea ice maps. I want to define statistically the season of maximum ice cover and separate these data from the season with minimal ice cover (and those with increasing and decreasing ice cover).
Is it possible to do this with a cluster analysis?
The goal should be that the data get a new attribute (eg 1 to 4 for the seasons).
With this new attribute the calculation of mean, median etc. for the season is possible.

Comment: Have you considered just converting the raster to vector? Would seem like a path of least effort. Vector data would be easier to handle as the spatial coordinates would be represented.

Comment: Hello Andrew. Yes, I have thought about it. But I have well over a thousand raster data that I would like to assign to the seasons with means of statistic (e.g the raster data of 4th of January belongs statistically to winter, the data of 6th of July to summer). I do not know how to convert such an amount of raster data to vector data. And if that is possible, how can I analyse these vector data? Is this possible with R? If yes, how? I'm grateful for any advice. Cheers

Comment: How do you know, before doing any clustering, which raster belongs to which season?

Comment: Hi user (should really give your self a name!). Ok, outside of bulk processing of the raster images I don't really have any suggestions for that. I'm a bit of a R novice myself, but I'm quite sure that handling raster file types would be very steep learning curve - remember that R is essentially set up to handle vector style information. As a suggestion - a quick google for "Cluster analysis in raster images" turns up this page: http://www.cdu.edu.au/itl/AII-RS/SAGA_GIS_TUTORIAL_ENG.pdf - SAGA is stand alone OR is bundled with the QGIS 2.0 download - might be worth checking out?

Comment: Hello Micha, each raster belong to one day (e.g. 3rd of June, 4 th of June and so on). I want to cluster all the data of several years to find out if it is possible to split those data in several groups (seasons). Regards Hendrik

Comment: You may try i.cluster in GRASS. It also works for time series. See the GRASS GIS wiki for hints.

Comment: R has both a [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) and a [cluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/index.html) package that could be used for this.

[Here](http://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3060&forum_id=962&group_id=294) is a code snippet - maybe it helps you to get started thinking about your data.

Comment: Hello cengel. Thanks a lot. This program really cluster raster data. Thanks a lot. But in my case I don't want to cluster a single raster data, but instead I want to cluster the whole dataset (all days) and want to split the dataset into different cluster. Example: 365 raster data of days are given. Now I want to split (cluster) this data set into seasons (for example 120 belong to season 1, 140 to seasons 2 and so on...). I thought about clustering a rasterstack or rasterbrick, but I don't know how. Do you have an idea? Regards Hendrik

Comment: You can add multiple layers, both with `stack` and `brick`. See the [vignette for the raster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf) for a discussion of `RasterBrick` vs. `RasterStack`.
I suggest you break your project down into smaller steps (for example data input, clustering method, data processing, or alike). If you run into problems you can post back with some reproducible code.

(ps. To alert a commenter that you responded to their comment, put an `@` in front of their name, like `@user22315`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try this:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal) 
#Define working directory
setwd("~/icedata") ### 

#list all raster files, im asuming they are tif files, change if needed
files <- list.files(pattern=".tif") #be careful if you have lots of data...!
ICE <- stack(files)
plot(ICE)

ICE.df <- as.data.frame(ICE)  
cluster.ICE <- kmeans(ICE.df, 4) ### kmeans, with 4 clusters

clusters <- raster(ICE)   ## create an empty raster with same extent than ICE
clusters <- setValues(clusters, cluster.ICE$cluster) 
clusters
plot(clusters)

ICE.mean <- zonal(ICE, clusters, fun="mean")  
ICE.min <- zonal(ICE, clusters, fun="min")
ICE.max <- zonal(ICE, clusters, fun="max")
ICE.sum <- zonal(ICE, clusters, fun="sum")
```

Comment: Hi @Hendrik, could you please provide the interpretation for last four code rows? The serve as identificators of: "Which tif-file belongs to which cluster (group)?"